# Django manage.py runserver fails with references to strange temporary pip build directories

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write a script to start the server in my production environment (using apache mod_wsgi):

```
 #!/bin/bash

#activate virtualenv
source ~/.virtualenvs/myproj/bin/activate

# install possibly changed requirements
echo "Checking changed dependencies..."
pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r /opt/myDjangoProj/requirements.txt
deactivate

# run server
echo "Starting django server ..."
#export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='myDjangoProj.settings.production'

~/.virtualenvs/myproj/bin/python3 /opt/myDjangoProj/manage.py runserver 8000  --settings myDjangoProj.settings.production
```

However, I alwas get this stacktrace: (installing requirements works fine, so I omit it)

```
Starting django server ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/myDjangoProj/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/localadm/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/localadm/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/localadm/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/localadm/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-w8vru4/Django/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
  File "/tmp/pip-build-w8vru4/Django/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
```

The directory /tmp/pip-build-w8vru4/ does not actually exist. Do you have any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: [Do not use runserver in production!](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port)

Comment: Use the modwsgi package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi. 
You can start the server by following the instructions and through the command: `mod_wsgi-express start-server` in your virtualenv.

Comment: Is `Django/django/contrib/admin/apps.py` being loaded from a `.pyc` file?  If so, that could be the reason why the nonexistent directory is appearing.  Depending on how they were compiled, `.pyc` files can remember the original path to the `.py` file even if it no longer exists.

Comment: For Django, better off using the Django management command integration of mod_wsgi-express. That way it will pick up stuff like static file locations etc automatically.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is generally we don't need shell scripts when we are using mod_wsgi.

refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ for setting up django with mod_wsgi

Second your working directory not seams to be django project root. switch to django project root or include it in PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Shell scripts might be needed if using mod_wsgi-express. Sounds like you might not know about it. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi